# Is there a way to do real hand detection when using ARCore?

Tags: machine-learning, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to do some real hand detection when using ARCore in order to expand some functions. Unfortunately ARCore doesn't support it.

So until May 2019, is there a way to do object-detection when using ARCore?

I have trained a model by `TensorFlow`, but it seems it cannot work together with ARCore.